# Write data to .properties file in assets directiry

Tags: android, properties, assets

I have "config.properties" in my assets folder and I try to get and write data to this file. When I try to get data (getProperty()) - everything is ok, but when to write (setProperty()) - I get "java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)" in my log and data in my "config.properties" does not change.
Here is my class:

```
class Property {

private static Properties properties = new Properties();

static String getProperty(String key, Context context) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}

static void setProperty(String ipAddress, Context context) {
    try {
        properties.setProperty("ip_address", ipAddress);
        properties.store(context.getAssets().openFd("config.properties").createOutputStream(), null);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have "config.properties" in my assets folder and I try to get and write data to this file

That is not possible. You can read assets at runtime, but you cannot modify them.

Comment: So, is there any other way to solve this? Can I use any other file to save data (not sharedpreferences, I need exactly file)

Comment: @JohnA: "is there any other way to solve this?" -- I do not know what the real problem is that you are trying to solve. "Can I use any other file to save data (not sharedpreferences, I need exactly file)" -- you are welcome to write data to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) as files, or via `SharedPreferences`, or via SQLite. You are welcome to use your asset as a starting point, make changes, and then save to a separate file.

Comment: could you please tell a little more about "You are welcome to use your asset as a starting point, make changes, and then save to a separate file." ?

Comment: @JohnA: Call `store()` on your `Properties`, passing a `FileOutputStream` to a file on internal storage or external storage.

Comment: could you also please advice, if I'll move my "config.properties" to raw folder I'll be able to modify them?

Comment: @JohnA: No. Nothing packaged with your app (resources, assets, Java code) can be modified by your app on the device. You cannot modify a raw resource.

Comment: What's the purpose of this method then `properties.setProperty(key, value); `

Comment: @eCDroid: You can modify the *Java object's contents*. You could even write that modified set of `Properties` to a file. You cannot use it to modify assets or raw resources.

Comment: Does that change the in memory reference value?

Comment: @eCDroid: If by that you mean the contents of the `properties` Java object, yes. `Properties` is just a subclass of the ancient `Hashtable` class, with code to load and save to streams. Since you cannot get an `OutputStream` on an asset or raw resource, `Properties` cannot modify an asset or raw resource.